# http re connection in android

Tags: android, http, connection-string

I am trying to create android application using HttpURLConnection API. I successfully logging and now trying to fire another query say (http://someserver.com/myapp/getemployeebyid?userid.) On execution of this statement I am getting following exception.

java.net.protocolexception: connection already established

I have closed input stream.

My code is.

```
mymethod(urlString){

                    InputStream myis = null;
                    URL url = new URL(urlstring);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLconnection = (HttpURLConnection)                                      

                    url.openConnection();
        httpURLconnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        httpURLconnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        httpURLconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLconnection.setDoInput(true);

        httpURLconnection.connect();

                     int myresponse = httpURLconnection.getResponseCode();


        if (myresponse == 200) {
            ResponseFlag = true;
            myis = httpURLconnection.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            contentAsString = convertIttostring(myis);

                        } 
                      else {
            ResponseFlag = false;
            somemesg = "incorrect response ";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception Ex){
        System.out.println(Ex.toString());
        somemesg="connection failed";
    }
    finally {
        if (myis != null) {
            myis.close();
        }
    }
```

}

Noow I have 2 queries.

1. Do i need to write connection.disconnect(); below myis.close(), seperately?
2. After login success I am trying to reconnect. Cant I connect once and fired the queries. Once all the operation is done close the connection?

Comment: `openConnection` opens new connection. Second option is more appropriate

Comment: Then why error is? if it is new connection every time?

Comment: every time you call `mymethod`, new connection is established. And since you do not close your connection, you get this error

Comment: 1. Call close on all streams that you create after you are finished using them 2. Call disconnect if you are sure that further requests to the server are unlikely in the near future

Comment: I think that here is exactly what you are facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834350/httpurlconnection-closing-io-streams

Comment: #1. As visible from code, I created only one stream [ie. myis]. I debug code, after successful login application go to myis.close() method. Then for getemployeebyname(), it again go to   mymethod(urlString); #2. I want to do all the opratetions before connection.disconnect()

Comment: yes thats what I am doing, and getting java.net.protocolexception: connection already established  exception.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34895/discussion-between-sanjeev-yadav-and-mocialov-boris)